# Is there a sanskrit term that covers the distinction/similarity between human & non-human nature?

Tags: philosophy, sanskrit, language

I find it intriguing that in English, nature is used in two interesting ways; that is Nature as in the world around around and all living things; and human nature, which is that conmmon to humanity; ie consciousness expressed as man. One might posit this as a microcosm/macrocosm distinction.

Are there similar terms in Hindu or Sanskrit that align with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same is also the case in Sanskrit and the term is [Prakruti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prak%E1%B9%9Bti). It is used both as human nature and the nature around us, that is the material nature of God [BG - 13.19]. It is also same as *maya*:

> *māyāṃ tu prakṛtiṃ vidyānmāyinaṃ tu maheśvaraṃ* [Sve. Up. - 4.10]
>   - Know that *maya* is Prakruti and the lord of *maya* is God

In scriptures, the human nature are classified under three categories as *satva* (goodness), *rajas*(passion) and *tamas* (ignorance). And these three human natures origin from the material nature which you can consider as the macrocosm:

> *sattvaṃ rajastama iti prakṛterguṇāstair* [SB – 1.2.23]
>   -*satva, rajas, tama* are the three qualities of material nature.